# jquery URL modification

Tags: jquery, url

How do I replace subcomponents of a URL using jquery.urldecoder ?

I can extract eg. the anchor using:

```
    var res = $.url.parse(myurl);
    alert(res.anchor);
```

I would expect to be able to replace the anchor using:

```
    res.anchor = 'MyAnchor';
    alert($.url.build(res));
```

But the anchor part of the URL remains unchanged.
I would love an example on how to examine if parameter 'language' exists. Replace its value if it does, append a language with value, if it doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a function given url: http://mydomain/path?param1=somevalue&language=gb#mybookmark to return: http://mydomain/path?param1=somevalue&language=de#mybookmark and given url http://mydomain/path return http://mydomain/path?language=de

Comment: The above example works if i include: res.source = ''; before the call to build, but I cannot figure out the params.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

> http://jsbin.com/ikasu5/5/edit

Just search the `lang` in the query string, substitute if not the correct one and reload the page.

Comment: You don't want me to do all work right? this is not a "please do it for me" kind'a Forum, it's a helping Forum!

Comment: No offense, but I was asking for help to understand jquery.urldecoder - not a hand written altenative.